# dayjs does not parse British English dates correctly

Tags: locale, dayjs

I'm experimenting with `dayjs`. Following the example in the documentation, I have set this in my HTML script:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.10.4/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.10.4/locale/en-gb.js"></script>
```

In my JS code, I have the lines:

```
var locale = dayjs.locale('en-gb');
var date = dayjs('1/4/21').format('DD MMM YYYY');
```

The first line correctly returns `locale` as 'en-gb'. However, the second line returns `date` as '04 Jan 2021' when it should be '01 Apr 2021', according to the standard British English date order of DMY.

I have checked that the en-gb locale file has the date the right way round.

How do I correct this issue?

**Edit**

I've since found that `moment` has the same problem when using `moment-with-locales.js`.

Answer (score 3):

This might not answer the question, in that you were asking specifically how tot parse dates using the local feature. But I got around it using the custom parse plugin:

```
const customParseFormat = require("dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat");
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);
dayjs("01/04/2021", "DD/MM/YYYY").format("DD MMM YYYY")
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the OP, this functionality isn't supported by the `dayjs` or `momentjs` at the time of writing this question.

Here's an ES6 solution to the problem:

```
// Create this utility function
function formatLocale(dateStr: string) {
  const values = dateStr.split('/');

  // Make sure string is valid
  const isValid = values.length === 3 && values.every(val => val.length > 0);
  if (!isValid) return dateStr; // don't change if date isn't valid (handle error however you want)

  if (dayjs.locale() === 'en-gb')
    return `${values[1]}/${values[0]}/${values[2]}`;
  // otherwise
  return dateStr;
}

// Usage
dayjs(formatLocale('1/4/2022')).format('DD MMM YYYY') // "01 April 2022"
```

Create a utility function `formatLocale` which can be used to to check the current locale of `dayjs`, if it is `"en-gb"` it will manipulate the string input appropriately to match what is expected by `dayjs`. If the locale is anything else OR if the string input is invalid then it won't manipulate the input string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the specific locale from dayjs.

```
import 'dayjs/locale/en-gb';
```

https://day.js.org/docs/en/i18n/i18n